# Is there a program that converts IPA to audio?

Tags: audio, software-rec

Is there a program that converts [International Phonetic Alphabets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) to audio?

For example, how do I get an approximate "audio" of the symbol [/ˌproʊ ˈsiː/](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro_se)?

Answer (score 5):

On OS X, open a terminal window and type

```
say /ˌproʊ ˈsiː/
```

You can also pick a voice appropriate for the language

https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-install-and-use-mac-os-x-lions-high-quality-speech-voices/

You could pick Daniel, for example, to use an English accent.

```
say -v Daniel /ˌproʊ ˈsiː/
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a bookmarklet which claims to work some of the time by using AT&T's text to speech renderer:

http://johntantalo.com/blog/ipa-tts-bookmarklet/

Comment: Sadly this bookmarklet relies on the [AT&T; Natural Voices® Text-to-Speech Demo](http://www2.research.att.com/~ttsweb/tts/demo.php) which is no longer available at that URL. *8'(